# Proper way to declare browser specific inline styles in React

Tags: reactjs

How do you properly define browser specific inline styles, such as webkit that start with a "-" symbol?

for example:

```
-webkit-box-shadow
```

Comment: `WebkitBoxShadow`. Just convert every occurence of `-x` into `X`, where `x` is any lowercase character, and `X` is corresponding uppercase character.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can be written as `WebkitBoxShadow`.
From the official [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/inline-styles.html):

> In React, inline styles are not specified as a string. Instead they
>   are specified with an object whose key is the camelCased version of
>   the style name, and whose value is the style's value, usually a
>   string. Style keys are camelCased in order to be consistent with
>   accessing the properties on DOM nodes from JS (e.g.
>   node.style.backgroundImage). Vendor prefixes other than ms should
>   begin with a capital letter.